# UIButton setTitle doesn't change title immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uibutton

I'm having trouble by writing and reading the title of `UIButton`.

My problem:

```
// If I execute this line of code everything works fine, the title gets changed in the UI
[self.lastButtonPressed setTitle:stringDate forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// In the next line of code I want to read the title I've set before, but everything I get is the title of the UIButton before I changed the title.
NSString *myText = [self.lastButtonPressed.titleLabel.text];
```

Is it possible that `[UIButton setTitle]` gets called asynchronous? If yes, is there a possibility to make this call synchronous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want `currentTitle` not `titleLabel.text`. Or perhaps `titleForState:UIControlStateNormal`.